# Do redirect pages need meta tags?

Tags: php, seo, metadata, redirect

Just curious if you have say an index page that redirects to another page, when search engines index the site, do they follow the redirect and scan the page it is redirected to? Wondering if I'd need to put a simple html structure in the redirect page with meta tags for proper SEO.

Comment: How do you redirect, a php `header` command, an html redirect, javascript, ...?

Comment: Simple javascript: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.location="home.php";
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pages change location, use PHP header function with 301 redirect to notify search engines that the page has moved:.

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: '.$location);
```

This is the most proper way in terms of SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will follow your redirection and no, you do not need to send any HTML content when redirecting a request.

Also, they are aware of the type of the redirection, according to the HTTP header you sent.

Under the 3XX section, you can find the list of possible redirections: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes